# Pentium J2900 Processor Microcode update

Tags: windows-8, security

This processor model is getting regular microcode updates for Linux (from intel website). As I know Windows is also delivering microcode updates with Windows updates. My PC manufacturer does not provide any BIOS updates (Lenovo), I checked the website of ACER and it provides BIOS updates for a different PC having the same J2900 Processor. 
It seems to me that microcode updates are also available for windows... but my question is if Windows Update will update my microcode? I am using Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I’ll give a direct answer to your question:

> if Windows Update will update my microcode?

Yes, as explained in the Microsoft Knowledge Base articles [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4093836/summary-of-intel-microcode-updates): Microsoft distributes the [Intel microcode updates](https://newsroom.intel.com/news/security-issue-update-progress-continues-firmware-updates/#gs.fZHfOnc) to computers with Intel processors using Windows Update.

Comment: In the Knowledge Data base is a list with processors being updated but J2900 is not mentioned here. Anyway I cannot imagine that this processor is not getting the updates since ACER is updating the BIOS (but unfortunately not my Lenovo). But I want to know for sure because I want to buy this Lenovo PC.

Answer (score 0):

The following table provides details of availability and schedule for microcode updates currently planned by Intel. Changes since the previous version are highlighted in yellow.
[image]

Comment: Please provide the source of this table.